# Guava AbstractScheduledService on server environment

Tags: java, thread-safety, guava, scheduler

What is the preferred way of shutting down an `AbstractScheduledService` running in server environment (e.g. Tomcat) when the application server is shutting down? Do I have to explicitly register a server listener for this, or is there a way to specify the service threads as daemons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to manage `Service`s (including/particularly in a server) is using [`ServiceManager`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.guava/guava/latest/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ServiceManager.html). Add all the services to a `ServiceManager` and then `startAsync()` the manager on startup and `stopAsync()` on shutdown. You would need a server listener for this.

It is possible to specify the service threads as daemons by overriding the `executor()` method of the `AbstractScheduledService` and returning an executor that uses a `ThreadFactory` that produces daemon threads, but note that if you do that, the executor won't automatically be shutdown if/when the `AbstractScheduledService` itself is stopped (though you can add a listener to the service that will do this just like the default `executor()` implementation does).

That said, I'd recommend `ServiceManager` plus a server listener. That approach should ensure an orderly shutdown of your services.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, my first thought was also a servlet listener.